# Show that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \sigma^2_k <\infty$ implies $|\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} X_k|<\infty $ almost surely.

Tags: sequences-and-series, probability-theory, random-variables, martingales, variance

Suppose that $X_1, X_2, X_3,\ldots$ are sequence of independent random variables such that  $\mu_k= 0$ and $ \sigma^2_k =\operatorname{Var}(X_k)< \infty$ for all $k$. Then 
show that  $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \sigma^2_k <\infty$ implies  $|\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} X_k|<\infty $ almost surely.

I was wondering how could  I use the facts: 1) if a martingale $M$ is bounded in $L^2 $ then $\lim M_n$ exists almost surely.
2) Orthogonality of increments of $M$ to prove the above statement. I would like to see the solution in explained way.

Comment: If $P(|Z| \ge b)  \ge a$ then $Var(Z) \ge a b^2$. Using that $Var(Y_n) < C$ and $Var(Y-Y_n) \to 0$ show that the sequence of random variables $Y_n = \sum_{k=1}^n X_k$ is uniformly bounded almost surely, and that it converges almost surely.

Comment: Then where are the orthogonality applied?

Comment: $Var(Y_n) = \sum_{k=1}^n Var(X_k)$

Comment: Thank you, Do you have some idea on the following one: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2221753/prove-whether-n-nt-mathcalf-t-t-geq-0-is-a-martingale-submartin

Comment: Did you complete this question ? Write your own answer then.

Comment: I got the idea you have provided on that. But wondering about http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2221753/prove-whether-n-nt-mathcalf-t-t-geq-0-is-a-martingale-submartin

Comment: Will you try to write below an answer to your own question ?

Answer (score 1):

Let $M_n:=\sum_{i=1}^nX_i$. Defining $\mathcal F_n$ as the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $X_i$, $1\leqslant i\leqslant n$. Then $(S_n,\mathcal F_n)$ is a martingale and 
using orthogonality of increments, 
$$
\mathbb E\left[M_n^2\right]=\sum_{k=1}^n\mathbb E\left[X_k^2\right]=\sum_{k=1}^n\sigma_k^2
$$
hence 
$$
\sup_n\mathbb E\left[M_n^2\right]\leqslant \sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\sigma_k^2.
$$